# get the type of String object - java

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the hierarchy of the Object - "String" using the below method.

```
public class test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String x = "Test";
        System.out.println(x.getClass().getClass());
    }
}
```

The first x.getclass() return

```
Output:

    class java.lang.String
```

then -System.out.println(x.getClass().getClass());

```
Output:
       class java.lang.Class
```

and anything after that yields the same result

System.out.println(x.getClass().getClass().getClass().getClass());

Shouldn't it at some point lead to - java.lang.Object??

Answer (score 4):

Result is correct since you are calling `getClass()` on `Class` instance. To get parent class you should call `getSuperclass()` from `Class` instance that represents subclass type.

```
String x = "Test";
System.out.println(x.getClass().getSuperclass());
```

Output

```
class java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score 1):

`x.getClass().getClass()` will **always** return the class object representing [`java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for *any non-null value `x`*.

That's because [`x.getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) can only return a `Class` object and you're asking *that* class object what type it is (obviously: `Class`).

What you *seem* to want to try is not `x.getClass().getClass()` but [`x.getClass().getSuperClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29). Repeating that last part *will* eventually lead to `java.lang.Object`, as you expected (and, if repeated one more time, to `null`).